# Boost serialize string *

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to create a serialize function within my class, called location, and send it after serializing. I can't figure out why I'm getting an error, but maybe it's because I'm trying to serialize a string*.

Here's a minimal example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

struct WithPointers {
    WithPointers(const char* of = nullptr, const char* n = nullptr) {
        if (n) name = new std::string(n);
    }

    WithPointers(WithPointers const&) = delete;
    WithPointers& operator=(WithPointers const&) = delete;

    ~WithPointers() { 
        delete name; 
    }

    std::string* name = nullptr;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & name;
    }
};

struct WithoutPointers {

    WithoutPointers(const char* of = nullptr, const char* n = nullptr) {
        if (n) name = n;
    }

    std::string name;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & name;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string serialized; 

    typedef WithoutPointers Location; // DOESN'T COMPILE
    //typedef WithPointers Location;  // COMPILES

    {
        Location l1("da location", "da name");
        std::ostringstream oss;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);

        oa << l1;
        serialized = oss.str();
    }

    std::cout << "serialized: '" << serialized << "'\n";
}
```

It works if we use `WithoutPointers`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: in server.cpp line 6:Serializer isn't available for basic string.

Comment: Why are you using a `std::string*` for `name`, instead of simply have a member `std::string name;` I can't see a reason why to use a pointer (that won't be de-/serializable properly) at all?

Comment: The string* comes from a lexer, and that uses a string*.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Boost serialization serializes through pointers /just fine/ (and there are important applications like runtime polymorphism and object tracking/aliasing in a graph). However, indeed this doesn't simply work as expected in this case. The question is excellent if not for the unnecessary cruft in the sample code. I'm fixing that.

Comment: @RobinThuranMalhotra I suggest you store a copy of that pointer so you sidestep the issue. As well as you completely simplify the lifetime management of those strings. Note how much easier the class definition became (and this is even with c++11 goodness, it's worse c++03)

Comment: @sehe that won't work. The serialized object is going to be sent over a network, and I doubt that pointer will remain valid.

Comment: Huh. If you copy the string there won't be any pointers in the first place. You missed my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be fair, I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work. It appears to me to be a kind of aribitrary limitation, potentially even a bug.

To contrast, here's a version that simply wraps the `std::string`:

```
struct XString {
    std::string s;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & s;
    }
};
```

Interestingly, using this everything works as expected:

```
struct WithPointers {
    WithPointers(const char* n = nullptr) {
        if (n) name = new XString ({ n });
    }

    WithPointers(WithPointers const&) = delete;
    WithPointers& operator=(WithPointers const&) = delete;

    ~WithPointers() { 
        delete name; 
    }

    XString* name = nullptr;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & name;
    }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e738c5ff6a6ea22)**

Prints:

```
serialized: '22 serialization::archive 11 0 0 1 1 0
0 7 da name'
Deserialized as 'da name'
```

### Summary

I'd still advise against using the raw `std::string*`. Other than that you should probably mention this problem on the Boost mailing lists

### Full Listing

For reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

struct XString {
    std::string s;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & s;
    }
};

struct WithPointers {
    WithPointers(const char* n = nullptr) {
        if (n) name = new XString ({ n });
    }

    WithPointers(WithPointers const&) = delete;
    WithPointers& operator=(WithPointers const&) = delete;

    ~WithPointers() { 
        delete name; 
    }

    XString* name = nullptr;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int) {
        ar & name;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string serialized; 

    typedef WithPointers Location;

    {
        Location l1("da name");
        std::ostringstream oss;
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(oss);

        oa << l1;
        serialized = oss.str();
    }

    std::cout << "serialized: '" << serialized << "'\n";

    {
        Location l2;
        std::istringstream iss(serialized);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(iss);

        ia >> l2;
        std::cout << "Deserialized as '" << l2.name->s << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm gonna go ahead and use std::string. I will, however submit a report to the boost guys. Thanks a lot!